# How to done a field Update the standard field value by changing the another standard field value?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, configuration

I have the standard field as account and Opportunity when here my requirement is to the if we set the Opportunity stage value is to be set to the "Closed Won" it's to be update the field of "Number of closed won Opportunity(Number field)" in account standard field to increased it's value by 1. So I don't know to how I make it in this problem.

By the Example I have the following requirement if initially the value of Number of closed won Opportunity field is "0".Then I selected the any one Opportunity in that account and change the stage as "Closed won" then it's to be increased the value of that Number of closed won Opportunity value is "1".

For answer's thanks in advance and please help me to solve this problem by without using of any trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this requirement you can create a [Roll Up Summary](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US&type=0) field on Account object which will count the Closed Won Opportunity.

[image]